# Centos 8 - simple command in a shell script run with sudo privelige says "command not found"

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, centos8

I'm trying to run script as sudo that's throwing errors on very simple commands on CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105 VM.

The script works fine when run without sudo. "myuser" is a valid sudo user.

Here is the script as run from the command prompt:

```
#sudo ./xtest.sh
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "shell: $SHELL"
grep abc *
ls -l
```

Here's the output when run as sudo:

```
shell: /bin/bash
./xtest.sh: line 4: grep: command not found
./xtest.sh: line 5: ls: command not found
```

Interestingly, if you "su" into root from "myuser", the following errors display (though the login is successful):

```
/usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
/usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
/usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
```

Typing `echo $SHELL` from the terminal in both myuser and root show the shell is `/bin/bash`

Any idea what the problem is? This script has worked on RedHat 7 and Ubuntu 8, and I believe Centos 7.

edit:

If you log into root and run the script, it works. If you run it as sudo, it has the same problem.  $PATH looks like it has many repeating entries (I'll post it above) but not sure why that would cause a problem with the running it as sudo.

Here is the result of `echo $PATH` from root:

```
usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/home/engineering/.local/bin:/home/engineering/bin:/home/engineering/.local/bin:/home/engineering/bin:/home/engineering/.local/bin:/home/engineering/bin:/home/engineering/.local/bin:/home/engineering/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/root/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Here is the result of running with `echo $PATH`

```
 shell: /bin/bash
./xtest.sh: line 4: grep: command not found
./xtest.sh: line 5: ls: command not found
/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/
```

Here's the result of running it with the "-i" option:

```
shell: /bin/bash
./xtest.sh: line 4: grep: command not found
./xtest.sh: line 5: ls: command not found
/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/xpg4/
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with root's `$PATH`. What does `echo $PATH` show when you su into root?

Comment: If you log into root and run the script, it works. If you run it as sudo, it has the same problem.  $PATH looks like it has many repeating entries (I'll post it above) but not sure why that would cause a problem with the running it as sudo.

Comment: The problem would be *missing* directories in $PATH, not duplicates.

Comment: There is a difference with running something as root vs running it with `sudo`. Do you get the same error with `sudo -i`

Comment: Add this to your script and show output: `echo "$PATH"`

Comment: https://www.linux.org/threads/cant-run-any-commands-at-shell.26897/

Comment: Good grief, how is root's shell configured? Something is redundantly adding a *lot* of directories to the `PATH` variable.

Comment: @joshimeranda - see above.

Comment: @Cyrus - see above.

Comment: @chepner - no idea - this is a random QA system. it probably should be looked into, but I'd like to know what's causing the problem with the script first.

Comment: `sudo -i` indicates that `.bash_profile` appears to be *replacing* `PATH` with way too many copies of `/usr/xpg4/bin`, rather than *prepending* them to the existing value of `PATH`.

Comment: @chepner - ok, makes sense. But would that cause the problem?

Comment: In the case of `sudo -i`, the *only* directory the system will look for commands is `/usr/xpg4/bin`. In the other case, it looks like something is only looking at a fixed-sized prefix of the path, and that prefix is filled with `/usr/xpg4/bin`, so the other directories are never checked.

Comment: @chepner, here's that replace: PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

Comment: Let sudo using your current path `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" ./xtest.sh `

Answer (score 0):

Passing current PATH to root with `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"`

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" ./xtest.sh
```

You can create an alias or a function in `.bashrc`

```
alias sudo='/usr/bin/sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"'
function sudo(){ /usr/bin/sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" "$@"; }
```